# Typescript array of items from another const array (from official beginner tutorial)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm following the Angular tutorial located on https://angular.io/start. I got all the way through it and am trying to practice building for production locally, but when I build I get this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
> this.items.push(product);

The 'product' being pushed to the items array is defined as such in the tutorial (in its own separate file, products.ts):

```
export const products = [ 
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Phone XL',
    price: 799,
    description: 'A large phone with one of the best screens'
  },  
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Phone Mini',
    price: 699,
    description: 'A great phone with one of the best cameras'
  },  
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Phone Standard',
    price: 299,
    description: ''
  }
];
```

Here is the file where I'm attempting to use it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { products } from './products';

@Injectable()

export class CartService {
  items = []; 

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  addToCart(product) {
    this.items.push(product);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.items = []; 
    return this.items;
  }

  getShippingPrices() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/shipping.json');
  }
}
```

I've tried defining the items array in these ways, but all resulted in some error:

`items = []`

`items : any[] = [];`

`items : {id: bigint, name: string, price: bigint, description, string}[]  = [];`

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful is you could provide more code samples (where the `item` is coming from) but I think if you are working with an array of objects you should declare an object interface. In Typescript you can't really do it like this

```
items : {id: bigint, name: string, price: bigint, description, string}[]  = [];
```

For objects you should declare an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
const product = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'essa',
  price: 700,
  description: ''
}

interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
}

// Array of objects that have the structure of Item
const items: Item[] = [];

items.push(product);
```

You also need to make sure that the `products` array have the type set to `Item[]` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I did attempt your solution, but got an error:
`Type 'Object | null' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Iterable<any> | (Iterable<any> & any[]) | (any[] & Iterable<any>) | null | undefined'.`

I updated my post to include the class where I am trying to implement the items array.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment) could you expand the example and give the use case? This seems to work:

```
export const products = [ 
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Phone XL',
    price: 799,
    description: 'A large phone with one of the best screens'
  },  
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Phone Mini',
    price: 699,
    description: 'A great phone with one of the best cameras'
  },  
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Phone Standard',
    price: 299,
    description: ''
  }
];

const items = [];

this.items.push(products)

console.log(items)
```

Comment: Edited the main post with the use case I have for the item.